# Inline SVG : external resource cannot be detected by chrome and opera

Tags: html, svg, snap.svg

This is [my site](http://www.pristineparadise.com), it works fine on Firefox, however, upon visiting it using chrome or opera, the 'picture frame' does not show-up.

I purposely set the height of the parent `<svg>` element to 0% `<svg height="0% onload="init()"...>`, and then, after all of the svg DOM structure is loaded, I set it to 100% height

```
function init(){
  mySvg=Snap("#mySvg");
  //....a lot of elements initializations
  mySvg.attr({height:"100%"});
}
```

Because of the 'picture frame' does not show-up, and because of the developer console on both chrome and opera display this error message  : `Uncaught ReferenceError: Snap is not defined`, i simply draw conclusion that the resource snap.svg-min.js (the snap library) cannot be detected (I have included it near the opening parent `<svg>` tag with this line below :

`<script xlink:href="/resources/snap.svg-min.js" type="text/ecmascript"/>`

Which is then begs the question : why? This works just fine on Firefox, does chrome and opera require different syntax to include external resource(s) into inline SVG?

Comment: I feel like you would probably have more consistent behaviour keeping all of the js code like Snap outside of the svg code if the svg is going to be inline anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the self-closing `<script ... />` tag.

Chrome is buggy here : According to [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#svg-mathml)

> "SVG and MathML elements whose start tags have a single "/" character
>   before the closing ">" character are said to be marked as
>   self-closing."

The SVG script element should be recognized as a foreign element inside an HTMLSVGElement, an thus the self-closing tag should be allowed, if it has no content.

To fix this, the best solution is to always use the explicit closing tag : `</script>`.